# ngIf Help Block on password form field throws weird error loop?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to add some help to a password entry field when invalid
But it causes a crazy error loop:
    Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined

My syntax looks correct. What am I missing?

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input
      type="password"
      id="password"
      name="password"
      ngModel
      required
      class="form-control"
      minlength="6"
      placeholder="6 character minimum">
    <span class="help-block" *ngIf="!password.valid && password.touched">6 character minimum for password</span>
  </div>
```

Plunker here
With span commented out
Uncomment it to see the error
https://plnkr.co/edit/AR761z?p=preview

Comment: Neither your component, nor your template, define any variable named password. So how could password not be undefined? Look at your email field: it has `#email="ngModel"`. Your password field doesn't have that.

Comment: Why do you think that?
It works just fine for the form field above that

Comment: No, that's not. Re-read my comment. If it was valid code, why would it break?

Comment: I am an Idiot, Thanks!